# Classic ASP: frequently getting just part of the page

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I'm using windows 2003, running some classic ASP pages.

frequently client get just a part of the page, looks like the page is not fully generated for some reason (refreshing does solve it).

I checked for a clue in event viewer, but there is nothing there.

Any idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Have you tested in different browsers? Use fiddler to examine the response from the server.

Comment: Well the problem it doesn't happen consistently...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this could happen because: 
- Browser cache needs to be cleaned.
- Memory corruption or insuficient ram in the client.

I would recommend further testing in several client machines and different browsers.